# package.json `exports` field not working with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript

The version 13.2 of Node.js allows ESM modules and [a new `package.json` field](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_package_exports), called `exports`, to select and rewrite exported files.

Before 13.2, I was importing files from the `dist` folder of my library with:

```
import myfile from 'mylibrary/dist/myfile'
```

With 13.2, I added this to my `package.json`:

```
exports: {
    "./": "./dist/"
}
```

And tried to import files with:

```
import myfile from 'mylibrary/myfile'
```

But Typescript raises the 2307 error, saying that module is not found.

Comment: Looks like it is tracked [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079).

Comment: Thanks! I also opened an issue in their repo. I will close as duplicate.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It has finally become available in [Typescript 4.7](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html)

Your library:

```json
// package.json
"exports": {
  ".": "./dist/index.js",
  "./svg": "./dist/svg.js",
  "./html": "./dist/html.js",
  "./package.json": "./package.json"
},
```

Your client code must have:

```json
// tsconfig.json
"compilerOptions": {
  "moduleResolution": "node16" // or "nodenext"
}
```

---

Prior to Typescript 4.7 you could utilize `typesVersions`:

```json
// package.json
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"exports": {
  ".": "./dist/index.js",
  "./svg": "./dist/svg.js",
  "./html": "./dist/html.js",
  "./package.json": "./package.json"
},
"typesVersions": {
  "*": {
    "svg": ["dist/svg.d.ts"],
    "html": ["dist/html.d.ts"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using TS 4.5.2 and It still does not work

Comment: It [didn't land in 4.5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079#issuecomment-1026476142) unfortunately. It has finally [landed in 4.7](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079).

Comment: @ThisCompSciGuy I can't get this working with globs. Do you know if it does?

Comment: Typescript 4.7, but still doesn't work for me :-(

Comment: @BenCarp did you ever manage to get it work, I'm on TS 4.7.3 and it doesn't work for me

Comment: @RichardScarrott, nope

Comment: It seems you need to set `moduleResolution`=`Node16`/`NodeNext` in tsconfig.json to make it work

Comment: @IgorSukharev Consider adding moduleResolution to the answer for visibility, that's an important piece.

Comment: Node docs state: '"types" - can be used by typing systems to resolve the typing file for the given export. *This condition should always be included first.*' https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#community-conditions-definitions

Comment: also note that this moduleResolution need to be set in the consuming project, not in the library's

Comment: My issue was none of these, but that I had not put a dot slash in front of `./` the dist-file for the non-main import. This works fine for node, but TypeScript don't understand it. So you need `"./svg": "./dist/svg.js"`, the `./` is important!

Comment: If. you are using a bundled app like NextJS use `"module": "esnext", "moduleResolution": "bundler"`

Comment: Can you please explain the need to export "package.json"

```
"exports": {
  ...
  "./package.json": "./package.json"
},
```

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else stumbling here after a seemingly endless odyssey of frustration and confusion:

> **Important:**
> Node Package Imports are supported **only** when `moduleResolution`
> is set to `"nodenext"` or `"node16"`.

- `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //                  ∨
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext"
    // <... config>
  }
}
```

If that's set, it'll work without a hitch. An example of how this may look in a project:

- `package.json`

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "imports": {
    "#util.define": "./src/util/define.ts"
    // <... etc.>
  }
  // <... config>
}
```

- `main.ts`

```js
import * as define from '#utils.define'

class Main {
  static {
    define.symbol(Main.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, "Main")
  }
  // <... etc.>
}
```

Answer (score 10):

### TypeScript 4.7+ full solution

The current top answer was not enough for me - I'd get the following error when trying to use the library in a package that has module: bundler.

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module X implicitly has an 'any' type. There are types at X, but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The X library may need to update its package.json or typings.

The full definition in package.json requires a types declaration in the exports. Further, if you ship both ESM and CommonJS, you need to use a distinct type definitions file (for some unknown reason) - I solved this by using rollup-plugin-copy

package.json

```json
  ...
  "main": "./dist/index.common.js",
  "module": "./dist/index.mjs",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": {
        "types": "./dist/index.d.mts",
        "default": "./dist/index.mjs"
      },
      "require": {
        "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
        "default": "./dist/index.common.js"
      }
    }
  },
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  ...
```

`types` and `module` are optional, for legacy support. `main` is also probably optional if exports are defined, if the package.json `type` is not defined as 'module' then it should be Common.js, otherwise ESM Also note that it's preferable to use .mjs extension for modules, there's also cjs extension for CommonJS (and .d.cts) but regular .js is fine and is most backwards compatible.

> Note that the "types" condition should always come first in "exports". [0]

If you use Rollup, you can use rollup-plugin-copy to copy the declaration file:

rollup.config.mjs

```js
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

export default [
  // ...
  {
    // ...
    plugins: [
      // ...     
      copy({
        targets: [
          { src: 'dist/index.d.ts', dest: 'dist', rename: 'index.d.mts' },
        ],
      }),
    ]
  }
];
```

Also [this utility](https://arethetypeswrong.github.io) can be of help to ensure you get this correctly.

[0] https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-7/

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. 
Although I didn't need to make a copy of the type declaration file. I used same path for both "require" and "import".

Comment: I did not check it in detail, maybe it's enough, but I know that the ESM files should be in .mjs format (according to the linked ulitility, don't have time to check this but I think Node.js needs it), for the same reason it could be that the type file needs to be .d.mts in certain configurations.

Comment: According to this question [0] .d.mts is needed if .d.mjs was used for the module. Note that there are many configurations in which a package is consumed, so just because there was no error in one configuration does not mean it won't cause problems.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72457791/typescript-packages-that-ship-with-mjs-and-d-ts-but-without-d-mts-how-to-i

Comment: I always forget the syntax for this and the docs are impossible to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

There is some work required on the TypeScript side to support this. The feature is tracked [here in github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079).
In that link there are also some workarounds listed.

Comment: this issue would be improved by inlining those workarounds.

Answer (score 3):

You can now also use `moduleResolution: "bundler"` in your tsconfig.json to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Building off the other answers, this block in my `package.json` worked for me:

```
{
    // ...
    "files": [
        "/dist"
    ],
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
        ".": "./dist/index.js",
        "./types": "./dist/types/index.js",
        "./generate": "./dist/generate/index.js"
    },
    "typesVersions": {
        "*": {
            "types": [
                "./dist/types/index.d.ts"
            ],
            "generate": [
                "./dist/generate/index.d.ts"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/node14/tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "module": "ESNext"
    }
}
```

And this is my file structure:

```
package.json
tsconfig.json
dist/ // and all its subfolders
src/
  generate/
    index.ts
  types/
    index.ts
  index.ts
```

Separately, I'm using TypeScript 4.7.4. Supposedly the `exports` field is supported with this version, but it didn't work for me. But this (maybe overly complex) workaround worked for me.

Comment: You need to set `moduleResolution` to `nodenext` in your tsconfig file. Only figured this out just now myself.

Comment: The `typesVersions` here will make the subpaths work, but note that if you use something like VSCode's ability to automatically add imports, it will no longer import from the lib's top level path. It will try to import from "[lib-name]/dist"

Answer (score 0):

While updating my Angular to 13 ver which uses typescript 4.6.4 I also met issue that typescript ignored some dep packages package.json->"exports" section as well as "typesVersions" (package has code not in lib root but in "dist" subfolder)
(Issue is describe here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33079)

So I used project tsconfig.json paths to overdo it

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@some-package/name/some-folder": ["@some-package/name/dist/some-folder"],
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few points that were not at all obvious to me when trying to get this to work:

1. The `tsconfig` of the **target** (module importing source) must be configured with a version of `moduleResolution` that's compatible with `exports` (eg `node16`, `nodenext`).
2. In the case where you're writing the **source** (module imported by target) but don't know what the `tsconfig` of the target you should consider structuring your project in a way that if `exports` fails, the package will still resolve [using a fallback strategy](https://github.com/andrewbranch/example-subpath-exports-ts-compat/tree/main).