# How do I import an individual module in a monorepo project in JavaScript/NPM

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo with the following file structure:

```
➜  yw git:(master) tree
.
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── add.ts
│   │   │   ├── index.ts
│   │   │   └── multiply.ts
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── server
│       ├── package.json
│       └── src
│           └── index.ts
└── tsconfig.json
```

Inside `packages/common/src/add.ts` I have:

```
export const add = (a: number, b:number) => {
    return a + b
}
```

I have the multiply version also defined in `packages/common/src/multiply.ts`.

In `packages/common/src/index.ts` I imported and re-exported the modules

```
export * from './add'
export * from './multiply'
```

The content of `packages/common/package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "type": "commonjs",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  }
}
```

In `common` project I run `yarn` and then `yarn build`, which generated `packages/common/dist` with content:

```
➜  yw git:(master) ✗ tree packages/common/dist
packages/common/dist
├── add.d.ts
├── add.js
├── add.js.map
├── index.d.ts
├── index.js
├── index.js.map
├── multiply.d.ts
├── multiply.js
└── multiply.js.map
```

now in `packages/server/src/index.ts` I have:

```
import { add } from 'common';

console.log(add(1,2))
```

And in `packages/server/package.json`, I have:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "common": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  }
}
```

So in `server` project, I am depending on `common` - as can be seen in the dependency.
This works, because when I run `npx ts-node packages/server/src/index.ts` it consoles log 3.

The question now is, how can I change the dependency definition in `packages/server/src/index.ts` from:

```
import { add } from 'common';

console.log(add(1,2))
```

to

```
import { add } from 'common/add';

console.log(add(1,2))
```

That is, import from the `add` module directly: `import { add } from 'common/add';`.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#exports

Comment: Since you want to use typescript for some reason you might have some issues with `exports` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990498/new-package-json-exports-field-not-working-with-typescript

Comment: wait, how do you mean? how am i using the typescript? i am authoring in ts so why should that be a problem?

Comment: Since I am using Typescript and in the common dist, the `.d.ts` files generated. Should that not work?

Comment: "Since you want to use typescript for some reason you might have some issues with exports" I am actually not using exports

Comment: I'm saying using the `exports` property of package.json you could import the module how you want and still have your build output to `dist`. The `exports` allows you to define a mapping between your import statements and module filepath.

Comment: I see. If you can provide a full answer (maybe with code example) I can accept this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @morganney said, you need to manually map individual modules to their equivalent bundle through `exports` in `common/package.json`. I'm answering based on a related [dev.to article](https://dev.to/binjospookie/exports-in-package-json-1fl2).

(I don't think there's globbing pattern support.)

```
{
  "exports": {
    "./add": "dist/add.js",
    "./multiply": "dist/multiply.js"
  }
}
```

You also have to manually specify each module's typing:

```
{
  "typesVersions": {
    "*": {
      "./add": ["dist/add.d.ts"],
      "./multiply": ["dist/multiply.d.ts"]
    }
  }
}
```

I've not played with this, but the article above on dev.to also puts a `package.json` path in "exports":

```
{
  "exports": {
    "./add": "dist/add.js",
    "./multiply": "dist/multiply.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  }
}
```